# Is there any way to avoid the page change in JavaFX pagination control?

Tags: java, javafx, pagination

I'm doing an application in JavaFX which uses a pagination control like a wizard for information input, so I need to do some validations before change to a new page, but I can't find a way to intercept the page change event before it occur.

I tried to add a `ChangeListener` to `currentPageIndexProperty`, but though this notifies the page change, there is no way to prevent it if needed.

**Is there any way to avoid the page change in JavaFX pagination control?**

Comment: I've never tried this, but can you just disable the pagination if the validation is not passed (using property listeners on the values that determine if the page is valid or not)? This would (should) simply prevent the user from being able to request a page change in the first place.

Comment: @James_D: The problem with this approach is that it also disables all controls on the page. Also some validations require some database query that are preferably non-automatable.

Comment: Ah, ok. That would be the "I've never tried this" part... It was an idea.

Comment: You can make your implementation of Pagination control.That means you need to reinvent the wheel but you can costumize it as you want....If you need some complex code i have you can have it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer thanks to the @GoXR3Plus 's idea, implementing my own `PaginationSkin`:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.PaginationSkin;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

class ProtocolPaginationSkin extends PaginationSkin implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    public ProtocolPaginationSkin(Pagination pagination) {
        super(pagination);
        pagination.setOnKeyPressed(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectNext() {
        if (getSkinnable().getCurrentPageIndex() < getSkinnable().getPageCount() - 1) {
            validateAndSave(getSkinnable().getCurrentPageIndex() + 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectPrevious() {
        if (getSkinnable().getCurrentPageIndex() > 0) {
            validateAndSave(getSkinnable().getCurrentPageIndex() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(event.getText()) - 1;
            if (index >= 0 && index < getSkinnable().getPageCount()) {
                validateAndSave(index);
            }
        }
    }

    private void validateAndSave(int index) {
        if (isPageValid() && save()){
            getSkinnable().setCurrentPageIndex(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `isPageValid()` and `save()` are private boolean methods of business.
Then, you only have to do:

```
pagination.setSkin(new ProtocolPaginationSkin(pagination));
```

Thanks all.